# How to select from table when exists in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When a lecture (a row in 'lectures' table) is deleted, it is moved into the 'lectures_deleted' table. This acts as a sort of back-up. In this case, I need to be able to call from both of these tables, so I would like to get the data from the 'lectures' table, though if it does not exist here, I would then like to get it instead from the 'lectures_deleted' table.

The code below currently breaks the website. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
function getModuleCode($id){
        $result = mysql_query('
            IF EXISTS 
                (SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'") 
            ELSE 
                SELECT * FROM lectures_deleted WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'";
            ') 
        or die(mysql_error());  
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return $row['module_code'];
    }
```

Comment: Are the 2 result sets union compatible? (same number of columns and matching datatypes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$result = mysql_query('
            (SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'") 
        UNION 
            (SELECT * FROM lectures_deleted WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'");
        ')
```

This way will also select from the lectures_deleted if it is still present in the lectures table, but according to your description i believe this should not happen.

Alternatively, I would suggest to use a 'deleted' flag (one bit field) in the lectures table, indicating whether or not the lecture has been deleted. This way you do not need to move a deleted entry to another table.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! 

The reason I have a separate table for deleted lectures is because it is only called as a sort of recovery option, and to make the software able to run quicker I wanted to minimise the size of the main table when queried.

Comment: @Ollie Moving data from tableA to tableB will not make your query run faster if you always select from both tableA and tableB anyway.

Comment: @Andreas It's only selected from both tables on a special backups page on the website, which will not be accessed often.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1 AS pref, * FROM lectures WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'"
UNION
SELECT 2 AS pref, * FROM lectures_deleted WHERE lecture_id="'.$id."'
ORDER BY pref
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is wrong because you don't return anything if the lecture exists in `lectures`, so you need to modify it like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'")
    SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'"
ELSE 
    SELECT * FROM lectures_deleted WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'";
```

However, performance-wise it's better to use the `Union`-operator in your case since it will only do one select (assuming that all columns in both tables are the same and in the same order):

```
select * from lectures where lecture_id=$id
union
select * from lectures_deleted where lecture_id=$id
```

Answer (score 0):

The IF... ELSE decision statement cannot be used in a direct MySQL query. It can only be used in function/stored procedures.
You can try this

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'") 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
   $result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM lectures_deleted WHERE lecture_id="'.$id.'")
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's not an exact answer to your question, but why not change your data model to have something like a column called `is_deleted` with a value of 0 or 1 in your `lectures` table? That way, you don't need to store deleted lectures in a separate table. You just have to include a WHERE clause like `WHERE is_deleted = 0` or `WHERE is_deleted = 1` to your queries to fetch the deleted or the non-deleted lectures (or omit the WHERE clause to fetch both).

If you want to solve it in your current data model, I'd do it in 2 queries. I don't think `mysql_query` will support your current SQL statement. So first query `lectures` table and if you get zero results, check for it's existence in `lectures_deleted`.

Also, I don't know where your `$id` variable comes from exactly, but you might want to make sure your query is not vulnerable for [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I've worked with both approaches and I've found yours to be far inferior. Much better IMO to union the 'deleted' rows when required than to have to filter for `is_deleted = 0` for every regular case.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Better in what sense? Faster? Easier to write? Easier to debug?

Comment: Less pain for the coder SQL DML coder e.g. not having to test `COALESCE(is_deleted, 'F') = 'F'`. Less pain for the SQL DDL coder e.g. can't simply use `UNIQUE` for uniqueness constraint because a value can legitimately be duplicated for 'deleted' entities. Better for performance e.g. not having to join all the way 'back' to the table with the 'is_deleted` flag.

Comment: The system (multiple apps, same db) I worked on that used this design frequently had bugs where the SQL DML coder would forget to test the is_deleted for an edge case, tester forgot to test this edge case and would be left for end users to fall foul of the problem, with is bad for everyone.